# DB2 Extension with xammp [Unable to load dynamic library]

Tags: php, apache, xampp, db2

I try to add db2 to XAMPP & php 7.4

this error is showen up

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ibm_db2' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ibm_db2 (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_ibm_db2.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ibm_db2' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ibm_db2 (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_ibm_db2.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.14 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2021 15:12:29) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

I used Thread Safety x64 because my phpinfo as following:

**System    Windows** NT 10.0 build 19043 (Windows 10) AMD64
**Architecture**    x64

dll files for extensions taken from
https://github.com/ibmdb/php_ibm_db2

I search IBM website but it was like a puzzle nothing was clear if needed to install additional drive or not.

**php.ini**

```
extension=pdo_odbc
extension=odbc
extension=php_ibm_db2.dll
extension=php_pdo_ibm.dll
```

note: no error shown when run php -m or php -v

**database.php**

```
   'ibmi' => [
        'driver' => 'odbc',
        // or 'db2_ibmi_ibm' / 'db2_zos_odbc' / 'db2_expressc_odbc
        'driverName' => 'iSeries Access ODBC Driver',
        // or '{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}' / '{IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit}'
        'host' => 'xxxxx'
        'username' => 'xxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxxx',
        'database' => 'xxxxxx',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'default schema',
        'port' => 50000,
        'date_format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
        // or 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u' / 'Y-m-d-H.i.s.u'...
        'odbc_keywords' => [
            'SIGNON' => 3,
            'SSL' => 0,
            'CommitMode' => 2,
            'ConnectionType' => 0,
            'DefaultLibraries' => '',
            'Naming' => 0,
            'UNICODESQL' => 0,
            'DateFormat' => 5,
            'DateSeperator' => 0,
            'Decimal' => 0,
            'TimeFormat' => 0,
            'TimeSeparator' => 0,
            'TimestampFormat' => 0,
            'ConvertDateTimeToChar' => 0,
            'BLOCKFETCH' => 1,
            'BlockSizeKB' => 32,
            'AllowDataCompression' => 1,
            'CONCURRENCY' => 0,
            'LAZYCLOSE' => 0,
            'MaxFieldLength' => 15360,
            'PREFETCH' => 0,
            'QUERYTIMEOUT' => 1,
            'DefaultPkgLibrary' => 'QGPL',
            'DefaultPackage' => 'A /DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0',
            'ExtendedDynamic' => 0,
            'QAQQINILibrary' => '',
            'SQDIAGCODE' => '',
            'LANGUAGEID' => 'ENU',
            'SORTTABLE' => '',
            'SortSequence' => 0,
            'SORTWEIGHT' => 0,
            'AllowUnsupportedChar' => 0,
            'CCSID' => 819,
            'GRAPHIC' => 0,
            'ForceTranslation' => 0,
            'ALLOWPROCCALLS' => 0,
            'DB2SQLSTATES' => 0,
            'DEBUG' => 0,
            'TRUEAUTOCOMMIT' => 0,
            'CATALOGOPTIONS' => 3,
            'LibraryView' => 0,
            'ODBCRemarks' => 0,
            'SEARCHPATTERN' => 1,
            'TranslationDLL' => '',
            'TranslationOption' => 0,
            'MAXTRACESIZE' => 0,
            'MultipleTraceFiles' => 1,
            'TRACE' => 0,
            'TRACEFILENAME' => '',
            'ExtendedColInfo' => 0,
        ],
        'options' => [
            PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_LOWER,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
        ]
        + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_SYS_NAMING') ? [PDO::I5_ATTI5_ATTR_DBC_SYS_NAMINGR_COMMIT => false] : [])
        + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_COMMIT') ? [PDO::I5_ATTR_COMMIT => PDO::I5_TXN_NO_COMMIT] : [])
        + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_JOB_SORT') ? [PDO::I5_ATTR_JOB_SORT => false] : [])
        + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_LIBL') ? [PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_LIBL => ''] : [])
        + (defined('PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_CURLIB') ? [PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_CURLIB => ''] : [])
    ],
```

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=ibmi
DB_HOST=xxxx
DB_PORT=50000
DB_DATABASE=xxx
DB_USERNAME=xxxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxx
```

**web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Route::get('/', function () {
    
    

// Test database connection
try {
    dd(DB::connection()->getPdo());
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // die("Could not connect to the database.  Please check your configuration. error:"  );

    dd( $e);
}


});
```

only one point I use for test

Comment: Which Db2-server-platform are you trying to reach,  i-series(as/400),  Linux/unix/windows/cloud  , mainframe z/OS?    Read the README.md for php ibm_db2 again, slowly, and more carefully.

Comment: db2 IBM i series

Comment: First install and configure and test the odbc driver for Windows ( i.e. outside of PHP)  option that comes with the "IBM i access" product.  . Then configure the php_ibm_db2 to use it (typically by ensuring that the PATH includes the directory containing the DLLs offering the CLI interface that php_ibm_db2 requires).

Comment: I am able to connect to db2 through ODBC Data Sources {iSerise Access driver} will you please explain clearly

Comment: The error message shows an incorrect filename "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_ibm_db2.dll"
(the expected filename is php_ibm_db2.dll , so check your php.ini extension line.). In your code, the connection string should include "DRIVER={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};" along with all the usual content, plus use DBQ=,your_library_list

Comment: this error shown 

odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code (just mask the userid and password), but otherwise the full connection string, and also show the edit you made to the php.ini,  and the plain text output of `php -m` (no images or graphics). If your _original_ symptom is now fixed, then you should open a different question, otherwise the question is a moving target.

Comment: update include more details

Comment: Does the output of `php -m` now show that the ibm_db2.dll module is loaded?  If it does, then your original question is answered, and you should open a different question with whatever is the new symptom (.g. IM002) and in that question show the working DSNs visible in odbcad32 (for which the test connect to i series works), and demonstrate you are using one of those DSNs in your php code.

Comment: ibm_db2 , pdo_ibm shown in **php -m**  but not in **php.info**

Comment: So both IBM modules are present in the `php -m` output, it means they are both loaded. So your original symptom (failure to load the module) is now resolved. Your current symptom should be a different question, as aleady mentioned.